# Vaio Smart Network on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, sony-vaio

Has anybody been able to get the Vaio Smart Network tool working on Windows 7?
I'm using 2.2 but the UI is completely messed up and it doesnt work.

I need to enable the wireless devices in my laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the sony vaio network manager is poorly written.
The problem in my case is caused because of the fact that it does not detect
the firmware parser device and therefore does not build a proper UI

The solution is here http://blogs.technet.com/teammb/archive/2009/09/23/my-mobile-broadband-card-with-my-sony-vaio-vhn-p19wn-does-not-get-detected-on-windows-7.aspx

Follow this exactly!!! Especially the driver for the "unknown device" is very important.

If you cannot find the files specified in that blog entry (if they have been removed
in the future... contact me I have backup)

Once this is done the network utility will work fine... but you might have
to toggle the hardware wireless on/off button sometimes to get the HSDPA module
to be enabled... it really does work now...just not properly.

Comment: next you get the hsdpa modem drivers here http://www.option.com
you will need your EMEI number

Comment: do you still have the driver & guidance? The linked blog post is gone now :(

Comment: I am afraid not. It has been nearly 10 years :-) 
A few years ago I gave the laptop to a family member, then just last year
they gave it back to me. It still works (I put linux on it) but I haven't used it since I switched keyboard layouts at some point during those 10 years.

Answer (score 2):

Sony sure don't make it easy, but it worked in the end.  Took me a whole day to figure this out and set it up, but it was worth doing because Windows 7 runs well on this tiny and incredibly useful little machine.  Hope this helps someone else.

Make sure you have a SIM card installed and the wireless switch switched to ON.

From a fresh Windows 7 installation, download these drivers from Sony Support:
(http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/vgn-p19wn)
7UPG_Alps Bluetooth driver, 7UPG_Ethernet Driver (Marvell), 7UPG_Graphics Driver (Intel) - NA, 7UPG_Wireless LAN Driver (Atheros), 
7UPG_Wireless LAN Driver (Intel), 7UPG_Audio Driver (Realtek).

Install the following in this sequence:

1. Graphics, Sound, Ethernet, Wireless LAN, Bluetooth drivers.
2. Sony Shared Library 5.3
3. VAIO Setting Utility Series 4.3
4. VAIO Control Center 3.3
5. VAIO Event Service 4.3
6. Sony Firmware Extension Parser 8.0
7. VAIO Power Management 3.3
8. VAIO Smart Network 2.3
9. Install the modem drivers:
   http://download.wireless-driver.com/driver/Option/137_Hokku_Option_Standard_Modules_3.1d0-1107.32167_41601P.zip
   Install the Globetrotter software it contains.

In Smart Network, make sure you switch off everything but the GPS and the Wireless WAN (cellular).

Then uninstall these programs in this sequence:

1. VAIO Smart Network 2.3
2. VAIO Power Management 3.3
3. VAIO Event Service 4.3
4. VAIO Control Center 3.3
5. VAIO Setting Utility Series 4.3
6. Sony Shared Library 5.3

Restart and reinstall these in the original sequence, restarting when prompted to do so:

1. Sony Shared Library 5.3
2. VAIO Setting Utility Series 4.3
3. VAIO Control Center 3.3
4. VAIO Event Service 4.3
5. VAIO Power Management 3.3
6. VAIO Smart Network 2.3

Make sure the Globetrotter is set as your WAN Connection Manager in Sony Smart Network.  You'll need your network's APN settings.  The cellular network connection is quite fast, almost as quick as my 3G Dongle.

Test the GPS with Visual GPS; connect the COM port that's labelled GPS Command not Control.  You'll need an area clear of walls, trees, clouds and large soggy animals to get a fix because Visual GPS doesn't seem to utilise A-GPS in addition to GPS and it doesn't pick up much of a signal. In fact, my external bluetooth receiver paired with the Sony P is much faster in getting a fix. The added advantange being you can site the external bluetooth receiver in the best location for a signal.

This website won't let me post too many direct links so you'll have to hunt them down on the Sony Support website and back them up because they will eventually disappear.

Don't install the Battery Checker if you want to use a third party battery.

Install the rest of the Sony software.

Run Sony Update.

Comment: You're right, added detail.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck with the links above.
Instead I downloaded the SmartWi Connection Utility (Sprint) software from the US support site on my UK Vaio VGN-TZ21WN. I downloaded [here](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNTZ398UXC&upd_id=4686&os_id=30) and just chose the model VGN-TZ398U/XC.
Once that was installed I could turn on the WWAN and use the GlobeTrotter software to connect using a vodafone SIM